# leak in UIImage?

Tags: ipad, uiimage

why is this piece of code showing a leak in the "Leaks" program?

```
    btnFaceBook = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    UIImage *faceBookImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.gif"];
    [btnFaceBook setBackgroundImage:faceBookImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I'm not doing alloc on UIButton or on UIImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently, testing leaks on ipad simulator is not a good idea since it shows leaks that are not found on the device.

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't leaking. The leak is in some other part of the code.